# Mini Cart Not Working in Mobile view in magento 2

Tags: cart, magento2.2.6, mini-cart, mobile, mobile-device

For **Mobile view**, I have added the **items in the cart**, the **mini cart icon** shows the product count correctly, But it will fail to trigger the **minicart-wrapper class** which means while clicking the cart icon, **failed to open the mini cart popup** to go to check out. Please provide me a solution to show the popup while clicking cart icon.

It works fine for the desktop, failed in mobile view

Comment: Hi Jaisa, I'm having a similar issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I extended Luma theme and changed basic colors and some layout. I also **changed the position of the `Cart` icon** and the Search bar to be at top next to "`Login or Create an Account`" in  `.panel.wrapper`.

Issue: turned out the `header content` was overlapping/covering `.panel.wrapper` , therefore, preventing users to click it on. So when users from Mobile devices click on the Cart icon, they are actually clicking on the `header content` div. I found this when I open the browser console and I was unable to select cart from the Element Select Tool.

Solution: 
1- Reverse my action and let Cart and Search icons be back at `header content`

2- (I only tried this from browsers console) 
Increased the `height` of `.panel.wrapper` to be at least larger, in terms of height, than the Cart and Search icons. 40px in my case seemed good. This allowed the cart icon to take it's position without being covered by `header content`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my theme, I have removed  the default cart icon, add created the customized one, so it creates an issue while clicking mini cart after I remove my changes  the cart icon works fine